# Why does ssh command fail whereas scp command succeeds inside of linux box on aws codebuild?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

On a linux vm inside of an automated codebuild CI/CD Pipeline this command executes as expected:

```
scp -v -i /path/to/key ./scp_test.txt user@host:$target_dir
```

However, a similar ssh using the same credentials does not:

```
ssh -vvv -i /path/to/key user@host "touch ssh_test.txt $target_dir"
```

The issue does not seem to be with connecting (part of logs is debug1: Connection established), authenticating (scp works), or permissions (have ran this command from local machine with same credentials).

Some relevant ssh logs:
Some Relevant failed ssh logs:

debug:1: Sending command: touch ssh_test.txt <target_dir>

debug:2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1

debug:3: send packet: type 98

debug:2: callback done

debug:2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768

debug:2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152

debug:3: receive packet: type 99

debug:2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0

debug:2: exec request accepted on channel 0

**debug:2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 5 len 0**

**debug:2: channel 0: read failed**

**debug:2: channel 0: close_read**